# ADT find method signature

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I'm new to Android development, and I'm having some figuring out the correct workflow for overriding method signatures in ADT.

For instance, for a Fragment, there are several lifecycle methods that should be overridden, such as onCreate(), and onCreateView().

Is there a way to figure out what the method to override needed for each method without extensive repetitive googling, or having lots of sample files on hand?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're asking is "Is there a way to enumerate all the methods that need to be overridden for a particular class?" for ADT (or any other IDE).

The short answer is "no, there isn't". However, lifecycle/callback/"hook" methods come into play mostly when you're talking about Activities, Fragments, and Services. They're also important in some View classes. By reading the API guides, you should get a broad idea of the important overrides you need to use.

Comment: I've noticed that when a class implements an interface, it prompts you to auto generate stubs.  Is there a way to get a stub for an arbitrary method?